# Why does my OBJ import has a white transparent overlay in Material Preview

Tags: texturing, obj

I am really new to Blender and 3D in general. I have imported an OBJ of a wooden water rower in Blender to make a quick assembly animation. Initially I imported a STEP file into Adobe Substance Stager to add textures to all the parts and then exported it to OBJ.

In Blender, I see in the Solid View with the 'texture' color on how it kind of should look, like this:
[image]

[image]

However, in the material preview and render preview, it appears to have a white transparent overlay over the model.

[image]

Anybody know what I might be doing wrong? Any tips are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us the Shader Editor in order to see if the materials are correct. Could you please pack the images and share your file?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @moonboots Hi really appreciate you want to take a look at it. Please find the Blend file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMew2MchoMPeUGv1mvy2E_X-xyRdfN2f/view?usp=sharing

It should have all the images in it. Let me know if it works. It's part of the 3D model, because I can't share the whole file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Emission* color needs to be black, or put the *Emission Strength* at 0, otherwise the surface will appear white:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Thank you so much!